# 2 column CSS grid, until a certain width

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, css-grid

I'm trying to model a CSS grid

I'd like it to be 2x2

```
xx yy
ww zz
```

While the screen is at least N width, I want each of the cells to take up 50% of the width, with a gap in between.

```
xxxx yyyy
wwww zzzz
```

When the screen hits a certain min width, I want the grid to stack

```
x 
y
w
z
```

If I start with this grid

```
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(50%, 1fr));
  grid-column-gap: 32px;
  grid-row-gap: 32px;
}
.grid-item {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}


<div class="grid">
  <div class="grid-item"/>
  <div class="grid-item"/>
  <div class="grid-item"/>
  <div class="grid-item"/>
</div>
```

The grid is always vertically stacked, since there will never be enough room for 2 50% cells, with a static 32px column gap.

If I change it to

```
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(49%, 1fr));
  grid-column-gap: 32px;
  grid-row-gap: 32px;
}
```

Then the grid will be 2x2, up until some minimum screen width, where they'll stack vertically. This is the behavior I want, aside from the fact that the grid vertically stacking seems somewhat accidental, since it only happens due to the `grid-column-gap`. I'm not actually defining a minimum width for my grid cells, it's just whatever width results in my column-gap taking up more than 2% of the space.

What if I wanted to explicitly define the pixel limit for the grid collapsing? What if I wanted this behavior without having a column-gap?

Comment: Just use a media query

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps a nice approach to fix this problem could be using CSS' media queries and percentages. You can use a code like below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Page Title</title>
        <style>
            .grid{
                width:100%;
            }
            @media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {
                .grid-item {
                    display:inline-block;
                    width:46%;
                    padding: 1%;
                }
            }

            @media only screen and (max-width: 599px) {
                .grid-item {
                    width:100%;
                    display:block;
                    padding: 32px;
                 }
            }
        </style>
 </head>
<body>

    <div class="grid">
        <div class="grid-item">one</div>

        <div class="grid-item">two</div>

        <div class="grid-item">three</div>

        <div class="grid-item">four</div>
    </div>

</body>
```

Another approach which is easier could be using **Bootstrap's** grids but as your question didn't have the Bootstrap tag, I didn't mention it.